# Load a fixed number of filtered messages in a Firebase chat

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Need some help with firebase. I read documentation and other topics and can't find the right solution. I have the chatpage with a messageList. I want to limit the number of loaded messages by 50 messages (so I use .limitToLast(50)). The problem is that I want to give my users the ability to hide messages from rude people in the chat. Their messages are deleted, the code works, but the number of loaded messages becomes 50-(number of deleted messages). I want to fix that number of loaded "normal" messages to 50 even if there are 1000 "bad" messages in front of them. How can I achieve that? Thanks!

```
  mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid).child("blocked");
  listener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                final Message new_message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                final String rude_message_userId = new_message.getUserID();
                mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasChild(rude_message_userId)) {messageList.remove(new_message);}
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
                messageList.add(new_message);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };

        
            query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("the_messages").limitToLast(50);
            query.addChildEventListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a counter to your if statement that checks for rude messages:

```
       mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid).child("blocked");
int counter = 0;
      listener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    final Message new_message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    final String rude_message_userId = new_message.getUserID();
                    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasChild(rude_message_userId)) {messageList.remove(new_message); counter++;}
                    }
```

then set an onCompletionListener for your query and query again limiting to your counter variable instead:

```
    query.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task){
query2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("the_messages").limitToLast(counter);
query2.get();
counter =0;
```

Comment: Trevor, thanks for your response! I've tried some kind of it but the thing is that if there are 10 bad messages the second range will be 60 messages and there is a kind of chance that there will be bad messages among 60-50, that makes us making the third query, and maybe the forth... it seems to be not very good for internet traffic, making such amount of queries any time for all users...